# Viewing all cryptocurrencies on a single wallet via its seed phrase

Tags: tokens, wallets, etherscan

How to view all cryptocurrencies on a single wallet via its seed phrase

Answer (score 0):

A seed phrase gives you a private key, which gives you a public address. What you want is to check assets that belong to that public address.

Unfortunately, checking assets for an address is not trivial. You basically have to read the entire history of the blockchain. In reality, you should probably use some service which already has this data - just check for external web3 data providers and data indexers.

Furthermore, a seed phrase may lead to multiple (active) public addresses. You'll need to repeat the process for all of them. I don't know if some service allows you to check multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with these steps:

1. Download and install Metamask.
2. Import your seed phrase.
3. Import all cryptocurrencies you have.